# Reference type not passed as reference

Tags: c#

I have this strange problem in my unit tests. See the following code

```
_pos = null;
Utilities.InitPOS(_pos, trans);
Assert.IsNotNull(_pos); //fails
```

The `InitPOS` functions looks like

```
public static void InitPOS(POSImplementation pos, Transaction newTransaction)
{
    pos = new POSImplementation();
    pos.SomeProp = new SomeProp();
    pos.SomeProp.SetTransaction(newTransaction);
    Assert.IsNotNull(pos);
    Assert.IsNotNull(pos.SomeProp);
}
```

The object `POSImplementation` is an implementation of some interface and it is a class, so it is a reference type...

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing a reference to an object to `InitPOS` (namely a `null` reference), not a reference to the variable named `_pos`. The effect is that the new `POSImplementation` instance is assigned to the local variable `pos` in the `InitPOS` method, but the `_pos` variable remains unchanged.

Change your code to

```
_pos = Utilities.InitPOS(trans);
Assert.IsNotNull(_pos);
```

where

```
public static POSImplementation InitPOS(Transaction newTransaction)
{
    POSImplementation pos = new POSImplementation();
    // ...
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: +1: See "Parameter passing in C#" by Jon Skeet for full explanation of this. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Yep, i knew that that was a solution but i didnt get what was going wrong. Now I do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
pos = new POSImplementation();
```

Just what are you doing there, if someone is passing `pos` into the method already?  Are you missing a `ref` attribute on that parameter maybe?

Comment: +1 Ref solves indeed the problem. I know also get what i did wrong

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** pass the ***instance by reference***,
you pass the ***reference by value***.